# WP app using TCP socket client can not connect to socket server

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I am testing a TCP socket client app communicate with Socket-Server in wiFi-environment.

1.) I am using VS2005 to create Console App for Socket-Server (Netframework v2.0)

1.1)  : Launch the Console App in PC with an IPAddress : 192.168.1.100 and portNo 3456

1. Using Windows phone as Client to connect the Socket-server .

2.0 ) set Up wifi connection in the phone.

2.1)  Start the App to connect the server in Wifi

the Client code to connect the server  ( No compiled error )

```
//-- taking idea from :creating a TCP Socket client 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx


            // create endpoint

            var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(hostName);
            var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portNumber);  // ( 192.168.1.100 , 3456)

            // Create a stream-based, TCP socket using the InterNetwork Address Family. 
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);       

            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();            
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = endpoint;

           ...... to do task here
```

1. Result show : NotConnected or Connection Reset

a.  can Socket work for windows phone in this manner ? Is there anything I miss out?

However, it work in WP emulator.

b. Any problem in communication between socket version in Netframework v4 for WP and socket ver 2.0 for WinForm or console App in VS25/ Netframework v3.5 in VS2008?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Does the firewall on your PC allow connections to port 3456?

Comment: I am not using well-known ports range 0 to 1023. Thanks